# Is there a way to record a continuous installation macro for the entire OS?

Tags: debian, system-installation

There are lots and lots of customizations made on a newly installed Linux distro during its usage (eg. within 1 year) to make it fit to user's needs. Every application we install drops or changes a configuration file inside `/etc`, we install applications which install their dependencies, we create some `systemd` services and such.

When we need to reinstall our environment, it takes a huge time and effort to redo every change in the new installation.

If we could start recording a macro starting from installation, we could just execute that macro to replicate an *exact* same setup. Is there already such a macro recording utility out there, or how do the system admins solve this particular issue?

Comment: Is Debian a requirement, or could you also use CentOS? If so, the anaconda/kickstart mechanism might be handy ...

Comment: I'm using Debian everywhere, but I could switch to any distro if it has a distro specific solution which can not be ported to Debian.

Comment: tried `etckeeper` already ?

Comment: The general solution to this problem is to approach it from the other angle: codify your installation using something like Chef, Ansible, or Puppet, and potentially (depending on your specific circumstances) containerise the host-agnostic application details.

Answer (score 0):

If switching distributions is an option, you could use the [Kickstart auto-installation mechanism](https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Kickstart2/) for CentOS.

The kickstart configuration file syntax provides directives to specify everything that would normally be asked in an interactive install. In addition, you can add pre- and post-installation sections which contain shell script code, in order to perform custom modifications to the target system. This will allow you to automate most admin tasks that you would usually perform by hand in a rather "intuitive" and reproducible way.

Comment: Kickstart is like Ansible and Puppet. Please see [this comment of mine.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/625856/is-there-a-way-to-record-a-continuous-installation-macro-for-the-entire-os/625881#comment1171343_625881).

Answer (score 0):

For Debian you might find this useful:

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed

We used a custom **Debian PXE image** along with a preseed file to set up Debian Servers. For the fine tuning part like installing systemd unit files I would suggest using **ansible**, **puppet** or another configuration managment tool.

With ansible you have something called a playbook which holds all the configuration on your workstation. You can role out a new service or changes to the system within minutes no matter if you deploy it on 1 server or 500.

The config looks like the following example and is easy to adjust to whatever distribution you have.

```
- name: Logwatch | Make sure logwatch and its dependencies are installed
  package:
    name: "{{item}}"
    state: present
  with_items:
    - logwatch

- name: Logwatch | Configure logwatch's cronjob
  cron:
    user: root
    cron_file: "{{ default_crontab }}"
    name: logwatch
    job: /usr/sbin/logwatch --format {{ logwatch_format }} --range {{ logwatch_range }} --detail {{ logwatch_detail }}
    minute: 0
    hour: 8
    day: "*/7"
  tags: cron
```

Comment: I looked into Ansible and Puppet. They seem similar and work by executing a pre-defined script to build an operating system. However, the key part I'm asking is the part we create those scripts. Scripts should be created continuously as we use our system, like a recording button left pressed for the entire usage, for months.

Comment: In this case your best bet would be to containerize your applications. Ideal with a orchestrator like kubernetes. Your base OS is only minimal and will not change much. All the applications can be changed on demand, they can scale up or down and so on.